# OAuth signature_invalid error using PesaPal API with Ruby

Tags: php, ruby, oauth

I'm having a real nightmare trying to get the PesaPal API to work for me using Ruby...

I appreciate that it's probably not the most commonly used API but if there's anybody online here who has more experience using OAuth, and/or PHP experience who could offer a fresh pair of eyes I'd appreciate it.

So the PesaPal developer site is here: http://developer.pesapal.com
Their [API docs](http://developer.pesapal.com/how-to-integrate/api-reference) don't give away too many clues about how to use OAuth with their site and I don't understand PHP well enough to be sure I've read their [PHP sample](http://developer.pesapal.com/how-to-integrate/php-sample) correctly.

Here's my attempt at implementing this in Ruby:

```
require 'oauth'
require 'uri'

key = '<my sandbox key>'
sec = '<my sandbox secret>' 

API_DOMAIN = 'https://demo.pesapal.com'

# An XML string of param data to include with our request
RAW_XML  = %{<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><PesapalDirectOrderInfo xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" Amount=\"12.34\" Description=\"Bob Test 1\" Type=\"MERCHANT\" Reference=\"808\" FirstName=\"Bo\" LastName=\"Tester\" Email=\"bodacious@bodacious.com\" xmlns=\"http://www.pesapal.com\" />}

# Escape the XML
@post_xml = URI.escape(RAW_XML)

# Create a new OAuth Consumer
@consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(key, sec, {
  site: API_DOMAIN, 
  scheme: :query_string
})

# The signed request object
@signed_request  = @consumer.create_signed_request('get', "#{API_DOMAIN}/API/PostPesapalDirectOrderV4")

# Join the pesapal_request_data and oauth_callback with '&' for valid URL params
@params = { 
  oauth_callback: URI.escape('http://localhost:3000'),
  pesapal_request_data: @post_xml,
}.map { |k,v| "#{k}=#{v}" }.join('&')

# This is the URL we should redirect to
puts redirect_url = "#{@signed_request.path}&#{@params}"
```

When I try to visit the URL returned by this code, I get: `Problem: signature_invalid | Advice: > |` back from the API.

Can anyone think of what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check out the pesapal RubyGem here ... https://rubygems.org/gems/pesapal ... it handles all that stuff for you.

Comment: Thanks :) A shame that wasn't around when we were working on this project

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by creating a method to manually sign the url. create your own method to get the oauth_nonce like this.

```
def nonce
Array.new( 5 ) { rand(256) }.pack('C*').unpack('H*').first
end
```

The signature method looks like this:

```
def signature
key = percent_encode( @consumer_secret ) + '&' + percent_encode( @token_secret )

digest = OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new( 'sha1' )
hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest( digest, key, @base_str )

Base64.encode64( hmac ).chomp.gsub( /\n/, '' )
end
```

This is the @base_str instance variable:

```
@base_str = [@req_method,
percent_encode( req_url ),
percent_encode( query_string )
].join( '&' )
```

This is the query_string method:

```
def query_string
pairs = []
@params.sort.each { | key, val |
pairs.push( "#{ percent_encode( key ) }=#{ percent_encode( val.to_s ) }" )
}
pairs.join '&'
end
```

You can then use the signature method above to get the oauth_signature param to use in the resulting url

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP was interested in a solution that addresses the Ruby domain, but I feel it may be helpful to note that I was getting a similar problem on PHP and the solution was to ensure I had no white space in the XML post data structure.

**WRONG:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PesapalDirectOrderInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        Amount="200" 
                        Currency="KES" 
                        Description="Computer Accessory" 
                        Type="MERCHANT" 
                        Reference="dd19f9ede4db6f0a13b7053111f02825" 
                        FirstName="Stack" 
                        LastName="Overflow" 
                        Email="so@stackoverflow.com" 
                        PhoneNumber="" 
                        xmlns="http://www.pesapal.com" >
                        <lineitems>
                            <lineitem uniqueid="29" 
                                      particulars="Keyboard" 
                                      quantity="1" 
                                      unitcost="200" 
                                      subtotal="200.00" >
                            </lineitem>
                        </lineitems>
</PesapalDirectOrderInfo>
```

**CORRECT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><PesapalDirectOrderInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Amount="200" Currency="KES" Description="Computer Accessory" Type="MERCHANT" Reference="dd19f9ede4db6f0a13b7053111f02825" FirstName="Stack" LastName="Overflow" Email="so@stackoverflow.com" PhoneNumber="" xmlns="http://www.pesapal.com" ><lineitems><lineitem uniqueid="29" particulars="Keyboard" quantity="1" unitcost="200" subtotal="200.00" ></lineitem></lineitems></PesapalDirectOrderInfo>
```